# Does RDLC Report require MS Office to be installed to Export as excel?

Tags: c#, .net, rdlc

I am creating a standalone application in WPF and I am planning to use RDLC so that i can export it in Excel & PDF format. My concern here is does RDLC require MS Office to be installed in system/pc where i have installed my standalone application? I should be able to download even if MS Office not installed

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create Excel (.XLS and .XLSX) file from C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c-sharp)

Comment: I am not going to use external libraries for exporting it to Excel. Here problem is if I use RDLC I don't have to worry/handle about exporting. RDLC viewer will take care of exporting functionality

Comment: @Ahmed ilyas can you please share more information on it?

Comment: Runtime libraries are not required, so this is disinformation.  The reportviewer control does all the work and doesn't care what's installed on the client computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't need MS Office to be installed (or other libraries) to export your report in a valid xls file but you need Excel (or any program capable of reading xls file) to view this file.

The same concept is valid for PDF file.

Comment: You don't need Excel to view the file. You just need a program capable of viewing Excel files. So Excel, Excel Viewer, LibreOffice etc